# AcquireTokenAsync method - Unable to get the token using ClientCredentials in

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Here I want to retrieve data from CRM and have registered it in Azure to to get Client Credentials and using it in below code:

```
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.WebServiceClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CRM_WebAPI_Test1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] atrgs)
        {
            MainAsync();
        }
        static async void MainAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                string organizationUrl = "https://OrgName<<URL>>.com";
                string clientId = "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b7ca-xxxx";
                string clientSecret = "key received from Azure App Registration";
                string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
                string tenantID = "orgname";

                ClientCredential clientCredentials = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
                AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID);
                AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(organizationUrl, clientCredentials);
                var requestedToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;

                using (var sdkService = new OrganizationWebProxyClient(GetServiceUrl(organizationUrl), false))
                {
                    sdkService.HeaderToken = requestedToken;

                    OrganizationRequest request = new OrganizationRequest()
                    {
                        RequestName = "WhoAmI"
                    };

                    WhoAmIResponse response = sdkService.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest()) as WhoAmIResponse;
                    Console.WriteLine(response.UserId);

                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        static private Uri GetServiceUrl(string organizationUrl)
        {
            return new Uri(organizationUrl + @"/xrmservices/2011/organization.svc/web?SdkClientVersion=8.2");
        }
    }
}
```

But when it come to line:

> AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await
>   authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(organizationUrl,
>   clientCredentials);

It directly exists the program and not giving any output, not even hitting the catch exception part. Is there anything I am missing here?

Also, how to know the tenant name while registering the application in Azure AD?

**UPDATE:** [Updating in question because not able to write down whole error in comment section so please bare with it.] After applying code changes as suggestion it is throwing error as below:

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException:
>   AADSTS50001: The application named https://orgname.com was
>   not found in the tenant named mydirectory.onmicrosoft.com.  This can
>   happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator
>   of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant.  You might
>   have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant. Trace ID:
>   58b1b994-eac3-4209-b553-4cea6a120500 Correlation ID:
>   fb8a3f3a-8b0c-4cea-90fa-88ea6e9a7208 Timestamp: 2017-11-29 09:09:37Z
>   ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (BadRequest). --->
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalException:
>   {"error":"invalid_resource","error_description":"AADSTS50001: The
>   application named https://orgname.com was not found in the
>   tenant named mydirectory.onmicrosoft.com.  This can happen if the
>   application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant
>   or consented to by any user in the tenant.  You might have sent your
>   authentication request to the wrong tenant.\r\nTrace ID:
>   58b1b994-eac3-4209-b553-4cea6a120500\r\nCorrelation ID:
>   fb8a3f3a-8b0c-4cea-90fa-88ea6e9a7208\r\nTimestamp: 2017-11-29
>   09:09:37Z","error_codes":[50001],"timestamp":"2017-11-29
>   09:09:37Z","trace_id":"58b1b994-eac3-4209-b553-4cea6a120500","correlation_id":"fb8a3f3a-8b0c-4cea-90fa-88ea6e9a7208"}:
>   Unknown error    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.HttpClientWrapper.d__31.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.d__22`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.<GetResponseAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.d__71.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.d__68.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.d__59.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.d__57.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.d__33.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.d__58.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at CRM_WebAPI_Test1.Program.d__1.MoveNext() in
>   E:\VS_2015\CRM
>   Projects\CRM_WebAPI_Test1\CRM_WebAPI_Test1\Program.cs:line 31
>           ErrorCode: invalid_resource
>           StatusCode: 400

Comment: Is `organizationUrl` something like: `https://contoso.crm.dynamics.com`?

Comment: No it is the trial account I have created with my organization, instead of `contoso.crm` it is different rest is same.

Comment: Okay, well the URI should be `https://yourorganisationname.crm.dynamics.com`.

Comment: Correct, but it is like: `https://betaversionName.organisationname.com` - I'm writing this after confirming it from **Service Root URL** provided in client's CRM.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if service root URL and resource URI are the same thing. Did you try my suggested URI with AcquireTokenAsync?

Comment: You meant for tenant ID or or resource URI? I have tested with a tenant ID suggested by you but not tried with any other resource URI.

Comment: Just for an update: I'm able to access the data from the browser's URI but even trying to get the result from **HttpClient** in C# code again its lead to **401: Unauthorized** status code.

Comment: I mean your tenant id should be your Azure AD tenant id or verified domain name. The resource URI when calling AcquireTokenAsync should be `https://yourorgname.crm.dynamics.com`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are using an `async void` function, which you should not do (except in event handlers where you can't affect the method signature).

So it should be something like:

```
static void Main(string[] atrgs)
{
    MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
static async Task MainAsync()
{
}
```

Essentially in your code when it hits an await, it returns to Main and the program exits.

In C# 7.2 you can also declare the main method as `async Task` so you can just `await` the method.

You can get the tenant *id* from Azure portal.

1. Open the Azure AD blade
2. Go to Properties
3. You can find the tenant id

The other option is to use any verified domain name (such as mydirectory.onmicrosoft.com).

Comment: Code suggestion solved my 1st issue but after that it is throwing the error as updated in the question.